# JQuery cycle lite resets back to first slide if you click anywhere on the page

Tags: jquery, cycle, reset

HTML is below, it cycles through these fine when I click on the prev and next divs but if i click anywhere on the page it resets it back to the first li in the list. Any clue as to how to fix this is appreciated.

```
<ul id="cycle_services">
            <li>
                <div class="service_header"><b>front-end web development</b></div>
                <div class="service_description">description</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="service_header"><b>back-end web development</b></div>
                <div class="service_description">description</div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="service_header"><b>web application development</b></div>
                <div class="service_description">description</div>
            </li>
</ul>
<div id="button_container">
    <div id="s_prev"></div>
    <div id="s_next"></div> 
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
    $('#cycle_services').cycle({
    prev: '#s_prev',
    next: '#s_next',
    timeout:0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
```

with

```
$(function () {
```

You are creating a new `slide` instance every time you `click inside the document`.

It should be created only once inside the document ready handler, but you were binding it to the click event.